# Shell how to kill a process and return 0

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible

Using **Ansible** i have this simple task :

```
- name: kill selected APIS processes on API SERVER
  shell: kill $(pgrep -f {{item}})
```

This process would be well killed but the task throws an error :

```
failed: "msg": "non-zero return code",
```

As indicated , maybe i should force my shell script to return 0 value (success)

`kill $(pgrep -f {{item}})`

**how to do it ?**

Comment: Note that `kill $(pgrep [...])` can be simplified into `pkill [...]` which might solve your problem as a side-effect

Answer (score 4):

The typical idiom to always return 0 is `kill $(pgrep -f {{item}}) || true`

But in ansible, it would seem sensible to use `ignore_errors`.